# Initializing instance variable for use outside of the method

Tags: java

I have a variable called "amount" in one of my methods but I need to make reference to it in another method.  I'm not sure of the syntax used.

Here is the code:

```
public static void startup()
{
    String message = "Welcome to Toronto Mutual!";
    //prompts user to enter their employee ID
    String logIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your employee `enter code here`ID.");
    int employeeID = Integer.parseInt(logIn);

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the transaction `enter code here`type, bank ID and amount all separated by a comma.");
    input=input.toUpperCase();
    if (input.equals("END")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int balance = 100;
        String []transaction = new String[3];
        transaction = input.split(",");
        String type = transaction[0]; 
        int bankID = Integer.parseInt(transaction[1]);
        type=type.toUpperCase();
... // there's more but it's irrelevant
```

How do I use the variable "amount" and "bankID" outside of the method?

Comment: I don't see `amount` in the code.

Comment: Don't see both "amount" and "bankID" in the code. But if you really need to reference it in another method, just initialize it outside this startup() method. `private string amount;` and do whatever you want with it in this method. You can read it from another method -- just make sure you're calling it in the correct order.

Comment: Or pass it as an argument to the method that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Pass `amount` to the other method through argument

   `private void otherMethod(int amount) {...}`
2. Create an instance variable so that you can access it within the class scope

   `private int amount;`

   If you go with this route, it is better to use getter and setter.

   ```
   public int getAmount() {
       return amount;
   }

   public void setAmount(int amount) {
       this.amount = amount;
   }
   ```